# how to make AutoFill information Textbox and validation of data using ajax, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have some doubts in php ajax scripts,when i select the employee id in the web page other table information display automatically.

My complete php code, js everything in the online drive that drive link shared below.

https://www.mediafire.com/folder/vylgll8mutl5h/

I am done with the project using drop-down list like when we select the state that shows county, like that but i need the script when i select the employee id it automatically fill all details of selected employee, Please help me on this project.

Thank you..

index.php

```
    <?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$query ="SELECT * FROM empid";
$results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
?>
<html>
<head>
<head>

<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function getempname(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getempname.php",
    data:'empname_ID='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#name-list").html(data);
        getpfno();
    }
    });
}


function getpfno(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getpfno.php",
    data:'emppfno_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#pfno-list").html(data);
    getdept();
    }
    });
}
function getdept(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getdept.php",
    data:'pfno_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#dept-list").html(data);
        getlocation();  
    }
    });
}

function getlocation(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getlocation.php",
    data:'dept_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#location-list").html(data);
        getesino(); 
    }
    });
}



function getesino(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getesino.php",
    data:'location_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#esino-list").html(data);
        getdesignation();
    }
    });
}

function getdesignation(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getdesignation.php",
    data:'esino_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#designation-list").html(data);
    getbankname();  
    }
    });
}

function getbankname(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getbankname.php",
    data:'designation_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#bankname-list").html(data);
    getpanno(); 
    }
    });
}

function getpanno(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getpanno.php",
    data:'bankname_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#panno-list").html(data);
    getdob();   
    }
    });
}

function getdob(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getdob.php",
    data:'panno_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#dob-list").html(data);
    getacno();  
    }
    });
}

function getacno(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getacno.php",
    data:'dob_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#acno-list").html(data);
    getepsno(); 
    }
    });
}

function getepsno(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getepsno.php",
    data:'acno_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#epsno-list").html(data);
    getdateofjoin();    
    }
    });
}

function getdateofjoin(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getdateofjoin.php",
    data:'epsno_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#dateofjoin-list").html(data);
    getgender();    
    }
    });
}


function getgender(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getgender.php",
    data:'dateofjoin_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#gender-list").html(data);
    getuan();   
    }
    });
}

function getuan(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getuan.php",
    data:'gender_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#uan-list").html(data);
    }
    });
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="frmDronpDown">
<div class="row">
<label>Empid:</label><br/>
<select name="empid" id="empid-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getempname(this.value);">
<option value disabled selected>Select Empid</option>
<?php
foreach($results as $empid) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $empid["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $empid["empid"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>Empname:</label><br/>
<select name="empname" id="name-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getpfno(this.value);">

</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>pfno:</label><br/>
<select name="pfno" id="pfno-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getdept(this.value);">

</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>dept:</label><br/>
<select name="dept" id="dept-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getlocation(this.value);">
<option value="">Select dept</option>
</select>
</div>

 <div class="row">
<label>Location:</label><br/>
<select name="location" id="location-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getesino(this.value);">
<option value="">Select location</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>esino:</label><br/>
<select name="esino" id="esino-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getdesignation(this.value);">
<option value="">Select esino</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>designation:</label><br/>
<select name="designation" id="designation-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getbankname(this.value);">
<option value="">Select designation</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>bankname:</label><br/>
<select name="bankname" id="bankname-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getpanno(this.value);">
<option value="">Select bankname</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>panno:</label><br/>
<select name="panno" id="panno-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getdob(this.value);">
<option value="">Select panno</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>dob:</label><br/>
<select name="dob" id="dob-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getacno(this.value);">
<option value="">Select dob</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>acno:</label><br/>
<select name="acno" id="acno-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getepsno(this.value);">
<option value="">Select acno</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>epsno:</label><br/>
<select name="epsno" id="epsno-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getdateofjoin(this.value);">
<option value="">Select epsno</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>dateofjoin:</label><br/>
<select name="dateofjoin" id="dateofjoin-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getgender(this.value);">
<option value="">Select dateofjoin</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>gender:</label><br/>
<select name="gender" id="gender-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getuan(this.value);">
<option value="">Select gender</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>uan:</label><br/>
<select name="uan" id="uan-list" class="demoInputBox">
<option value="">Select uan</option>
</select>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

dbcontrollar.php

```
<?php
class DBController {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $database = "data";
    private $conn;

    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
    }

    function connectDB() {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
        mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
        return $conn;
    }

    function runQuery($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }       
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }

    function numRows($query) {
        $result  = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;   
    }
}
?>
```

getempname.php

```
<?php
require_once ("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if (! empty($_POST["empname_ID"])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM empname WHERE name_ID = '" . $_POST["empname_ID"] . "'";
    $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
    ?>
<option value disabled selected>Select name</option>
<?php
    foreach ($results as $empname) {
        ?>
<option value="<?php echo $empname["name_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $empname["empname"]; ?></option>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

getpfno.php

```
<?php
require_once ("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if (! empty($_POST["emppfno_id"])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM pfno WHERE pf_id = '" . $_POST["emppfno_id"] . "'";
    $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
    ?>
<option value disabled selected>Select employee pfno</option>
<?php
    foreach ($results as $epfno) {
        ?>
<option value="<?php echo $epfno["pf_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $epfno["pfno"]; ?></option>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

getdept.php

```
<?php
require_once ("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if (! empty($_POST["pfno_id"])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM dept WHERE dept_id = '" . $_POST["pfno_id"] . "'";
    $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
    ?>
<option value disabled selected>Select department</option>
<?php
    foreach ($results as $deprt) {
        ?>
<option value="<?php echo $deprt["dept_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $deprt["dept"]; ?></option>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you better put your script here. Sorry, but i'm to lazy to open mediafire

Comment: Just paste the code in which you are facing problem

Comment: @bhanusengar Yes, i paste the code. please help me on this

Comment: @bhanusengar are u seen the attached code, please help me on this script

Comment: @MyNameIs hai i attached the code please help me

Comment: @MyNameIs yes i want, the given script is When i select the Empid on the index.php web-page, in other text boxes display that employee related data using drop-down boxes, but i want the script for when i select the Empid it automatically fills the all the text boxes at a time without drop-down

Comment: are there any error ? and in your `getempname(val)` add this line `console.log(data)`  , and check the browser console if the data is showing or not

Comment: and you forget to add parameter on `getpfno();`

Comment: @MyNameIs Yes i am getting error

Comment: @MyNameIs and tell me which parameter is forget on `getpfno();`

Comment: inside the `success(){}` inside your `getempname(val)`

Comment: that is not a issue, script is working fine but my question is how to make auto-fill text boxes like when i select the employee id in the web page other text boxes fills autocratically. so need the help on this

Comment: @MyNameIs https://demo.smarttutorials.net/jqueryui-autocomplete-with-multiple-input-fields Like this i want, when i select the COUNTRY NAME automatically it display the other tabs

Comment: @MyNameIs please check the above link please

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getempname(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getempname.php",
    data:'empname_ID='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#name-list").html(data);
        $("#useraddress").val(data.address);
        getpfno();
    }
    });
}
```

and here is your textbox for an example.

```
<input type="text" name="address" id="useraddress" >
```

By the way i need to the ajax result too.

Comment: Nothing happens in this script, still it is working like drop-down basis only

Comment: give me a suggestion for this code onchange function to autochange  `</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>Empname:</label><br/>
<select name="empname" id="name-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getpfno(this.value);">

</select>`

Comment: @Chiru are you already add the textbox ? because in your script i didn't see any textbox

Comment: no did't add the textbox, just i change the id value in option tag in my  script data will display in the dropdown menu text-boxes

Comment: No one is there to answer this question. no one is know the script for auto complete text box by selecting the another text box, if i ask the question in **stack overflow** some one give the vote down'(This question is does not any research effort; it is unclear, or not useful)`, this question is not useful for you please leave it, but it is useful for me. today i am feel bad by the stack-overflow answer writers so i am deleting my stack-overflow account,

Comment: @Chiru . feel sorry for not helping. i'm not that good but i'm trying. Ok, first try to `cut` some of your code above so you will only have two `selectbox` and don't delete your SO account, you'll need it.